# Have Stack Exchange users collaborated to create projects?

Tags: discussion, collaboration

Are there any examples of users meeting on Stack Exchange (more specifically Stack Overflow) that lead to a successful project collaboration? Maybe even a publicly known project the rest of us have heard of?

Is there a platform for this here? Other than first connecting being through comments and chats, does Stack Exchange facilitate any sort of a [crowdsourcing](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiUuszAh8fXAhUCqFQKHYoYBA4QFgg1MAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCrowdsourcing&usg=AOvVaw3NqrjP5jMwhoQAvVQ9Hstr) platform?

Comment: This may be *[possibly related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139934/is-stack-overflow-a-collaborative-or-cooperative-platform)*

Comment: @JakeSymons Really? Jeez, that takes some good piece of imagination from your side or a viciously poor formulation from my side.

Comment: You write "Does it exist a platform for it here.. " so "Is Stack Overflow a Collaborative or Cooperative platform?" does appear to be related to that

Comment: @6'whitemale Ok, related. Good job in finding the related link. Any input on other, more important, questions in the question?

Comment: I've accidentally inspired a few pieces of FOSS software, does that count? ;p

Comment: @JourneymanGeek haha exactly. But do you get rep royalty? :-P

Answer (score 13):

Sure. There's an entire Stack Exchange site devoted to it, if I understand what you're talking about.

[Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) is a place for users to create apps that utilize the Stack Exchange API to make scripts to help users do Stack Exchange. Many of the projects there are collaborative.

But, the best example, though still Stack Exchange related would be [Charcoal](http://charcoal-se.org/) and  Smoke Detector.  In an effort to combat spam on the SE network, [a group of users](https://charcoal-se.org/people) are working together to automatically detect and flag spam posts. They're even getting some general notoriety, taking part in [this keynote](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WAKc8QUdOOM) by Tanmay Bakshi at the Open Source Summit.

I'm sure there are other similar examples, even ones that don't relate to SE specifically, though I don't know of them off the top of my head.

Comment: Great answer. Though I was specifically looking for SE unrelated projects.